# Python module not found - subdirectory

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, pdf2image

My main script reads another script that lies in a sub-folder "models".
Codes had been working perfectly until recent tech refresh/whole machine updates.
**Error reads: Module not found**. Error also happens when I try to import a library which ran perfectly previously. No issue with importing other libraries like tensorflow & keras though. Suspect issues with calling path directory but not sure how to approach and resolve.

```
from models.model import *
import pdf2image
```

The project structure is as follows. I will run mainscript.py for this project.

```
/project/mainscript.py
/project/models/model.py
```

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: show your project structure

Comment: @drum Updated post with project structure:
/project/mainscript.py
/project/models/model.py

Comment: do you have `models/__init__.py `?

Comment: i dont have that. previously didnt have that separate program and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

It is good to edit python include path.

```py
import os, sys
sys.path.append(f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/models")

from models import *
```